# Perturbative reheating

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Are there any inflation models in which reheating would start perturbatively? I mean the non-perturbative process named as preheating (via parametric resonance) would be either inefficient or absent in those models.